# call javascript function from code behind with parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

i am generating a anchor from code behind and on its onclick function i want to call javascript function with string as a argument. 
i am trying this:-

```
 function show(data)
  {
        alert(data);
  }
```

and calling :-

```
 string data = "<a onclick='show(\""+Task+"\")' >" + anchor inner text + "</a>";
```

i am adding this string to a table cell and my project requirement is, when user click on that specific cell a popup show the content which i pass as an argument to javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

```
string data = "<a onclick='show(\""+Task+"\")' >" + anchor inner text + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Much more cleaner approach would be storing that value in data-attribute:

```
<td data-message='Hello World!'>Click me!</td>
```

And replacing your function with jQuery:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('message'));
});​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BEYK8/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to use RegisterStartupScript Method to do that.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello World!') </");
sb.Append("script>");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one quote:

```
 string data = "<a onclick='show(\""+Task+"\") >" + anchor inner text + "</a>";
```

to

```
 string data = "<a onclick='show(\""+Task+"\")' >" + anchor inner text + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
$('td a').click(function(){

  var currLink=$(this);
  alert(currLink.text());//shows the inner text of anchor
  return false;//prevent default
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href='' onclick='return check(\""+Task+"\")'>check</a> 

<script type='text/javascript'>  

function check() 
{    
 alert(data); 
}  
</script>
```

try Something  like this. Code is not tested may get compile error